# Force a window without default window controls to open with specific dimensions

Tags: windows, windows-10, window

I have a program which does not implement the standard Windows window controls (i.e. title bar and frame).

[image: Image of the offending app, you will notice it has its own window controls]

I would like to force this window to open with a given size but I believe not using the standard window controls is affecting all the usual solutions like Power Toys' FancyZones.

Is there a workaround for this? Some way to force the default title bar perhaps?

Comment: You could use a third-party tool, such as free *Window Resizer*, https://vovsoft.com/software/window-resizer/ , or an alternative, https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-resize-an-unresizable-window-or-dialog-box/, *if* the window responds to the tool. Other than that, you'd need to rewrite the application.

Answer (score 0):

**SizeWindow.exe**. Changes the size of a window

*This uses the inbuilt compilers in Windows 10 - there are three VB.NET compilers, three JScript compilers, and three C# compilers.*

Just copy each text file into the same folder and double click the batch file to make the program.

```
REM SizeWindow.bat
REM This file compiles SizeWindow.vb to SizeWindow.exe
REM SizeWindow changes the size of a window
REM To use 
REM SizeWindow nnnnxnnnn <Window title>
REM E.G.
REM SizeWindow 300x400 Untitled - Notepad
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:winexe /out:"%~dp0\SizeWindow.exe" "%~dp0\SizeWindow.vb" /verbose
pause
```

---

```
'SizeWindow.vb
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Module TopMost
    Public Declare UNICODE Function FindWindowW Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    Public Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal wFlags As Integer) As Integer
    Public Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
    Public Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
    Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
    Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
    Public Const SWP_NOZORDER = &h4

    Sub Main()
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim hWindows as IntPtr
        Dim CmdLine as String
        Dim Ret as Integer
        CmdLine = Command()
        Dim A as String()
        Dim B as String()
        A = Split(CmdLine, Chr(32), 2, 1)
        B = Split(A(0), "x", 2, 1)
        hwindows = FindWindowW(vbNullString, A(1))
        If hwindows = 0 then
            Msgbox(A(1) & " cannot be found.")
        Else
            Ret = SetWindowPos(hwindows, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, B(0), B(1), SWP_NOMOVE + SWP_NOZORDER)
            If Ret = 0 Then MsgBox("Set Pos Error is " & Err.LastDllError)
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

**To use**

```
SizeWindow 300x400 Untitled - Notepad
```

From https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2021/03/sizewindowexe-changes-size-of-window.html

---

If you need to know the title or the class name see Winlist.exe https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/winlistexe-list-open-windows-and-their.html.

It gives output like this with this command

```
WinList.exe" | Findstr /c:notepad
```

---

```
Window Text                             Class Name                             Unicode HWnd    ParentHWnd      ProcessID       ThreadID    Process Name
MSCTFIME UI                            MSCTFIME UI                              True    1770634 65668   3432    8228    notepad.exe
Default IME                            IME                                      True    1049692 65668   3432    8228    notepad.exe
Untitled - Notepad                     Notepad                                  True    460174  65668   3432    8228    notepad.exe
   «No Window Text»                    Edit                                     True    591400  460174  3432    8228    notepad.exe
   «No Window Text»                    msctls_statusbar32       True    1114996 460174  3432    8228    notepad.exe
```